# Dividing each row in a pandas dataframe by a specific row in the same pandas dataframe based on another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Reproducible Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(zip(['TN10', 'GBL', 'GBM', 'GBS'], [0.10, 0.15, 0.12, 0.13])),
    columns=['underlying','volatility']
)
df_spread = pd.DataFrame(
    list(zip(['GBL', 'GBM', 'GBS'], ['TN10', 'GBL', 'GBL'])),
    columns=['underlying','spread_underlying']
)
df = pd.merge(
    df, 
    df_spread,
    on=['underlying'],
    how='left'
)
```

I am now trying to find the most efficient way (speed is quite important here) to do the following:

- The spread underlying dataframe specifies for each underlying a certain spread underlying
- If GBL has TN10 as spread underlying, then I want to divide the GBL row by the TN10 row.
- If GBM has GBL as spread underlying, then I want to divide the GBM row by the GBL row.
- If GBS has GBL as spread underlying, then I want to divide the GBS row by the GBL row.

I have now just limited the reproducible example to one column called volatility, but this could be an arbitrary amount of column so I am looking for a general solution.

Hopefully somebody can help me with this problem.

Regards,

Guyon

In the case where there is not a dataframe of spread underlyings but just a single spread underlying, I use the following code (Maybe this can be improved for speed as well but just an idea of where errors could arise):

```
def get_spread(df, spread_underlyin):
    if not spread_underlying:
        return df

    if (df['underlying'] == spread_underlying).any():
        spread_underlying_row = df.loc[df['underlying'] == spread_underlying, 'rvol_0':'rvol_lookback_4'].iloc[0]
        df.loc[
           df['underlying'] != spread_underlying,
           'rvol_0':'rvol_lookback_4'
        ] /= spread_underlying_row

    return df
```

EDIT:
for a single column this seems to work, but I can't seem to extend it to more than one column:

```
df['volatility'] = df['volatility'] - df['spread_underlying'].map(df.set_index('underlying')['volatility'])
```

Comment: Are you looking to self-merge? `df.merge(df, left_on="spread_underlying", right_on="underlying", how="left")` - then you can perform your calculation on the 2 volatile values?